# Memory allocation test in C - How to write a CUnit-Test for malloc and free?

Tags: c, testing, malloc, free, cunit

since a few days I am stuck with a Test for one of my applications that i can't fix. So i decide to write a test for my test...

I want to allocate memeory, watch the grown of the memory in use and than free the memory again. I excpect that the allocated memory is not in use anymore, right?

I am working on Mac OSX (10.6.8) and gcc (GCC) 4.2.1

so i write this test:

```
void testMemoryFreeCheck(){
    puts("- test Memory Free Check  -");
    puts("- ----------------------- -");
    puts("- This test takes a while -");
    puts("");
    struct rusage rus;
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &rus);

    // Things befor we want to mature. 
    char *holder[10000];
    char *bigHolder;
    int loops =  10000;
    int i;

    // Variables used for tests. 
    long int afterFirstTestKiloByte = 0;
    long int afterSecondTestKiloByte = 0;
    long int afterThirdTestKiloByte = 0;
    long int afterForuthTestKiloByte = 0;

    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &rus);
    long int initialKiloByte = rus.ru_maxrss;
    printf("Initial KB Used: %ld\n", initialKiloByte);

    // a adder to proof that we get it write
    char add = "A";
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &rus);
    long int afterAddKiloByte = rus.ru_maxrss;
    printf("After a char add KB Used: %ld\n", initialKiloByte);
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &rus);
    long int growingKiloByte = rus.ru_maxrss;

    // This loop should do nothing.
    for(i=0; i<loops; ++i){
        printf(".");
    }
    puts("");
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &rus);
    afterFirstTestKiloByte = rus.ru_maxrss;
    printf("First Test should be 0 : %ld\n", (afterFirstTestKiloByte - afterAddKiloByte));
    CU_ASSERT_TRUE( (afterFirstTestKiloByte - afterAddKiloByte) == 0);

    // This loop should free all allocated space.
    for(i=0; i<(loops * 128); ++i){
        char *tmp = malloc(1024 * 1024);
        free(tmp);
    }

    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &rus);
    afterSecondTestKiloByte = rus.ru_maxrss;
    printf("Second Test should be 0 (4096 is ok for some reasons): %ld\n", (afterSecondTestKiloByte - afterAddKiloByte));
    CU_ASSERT_TRUE( (afterSecondTestKiloByte - afterAddKiloByte) <= 4096);

    // This loop should increase the allocated space.
    for(i=0; i<loops; ++i){
        holder[i] = malloc(1024 * 1024);
    }
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &rus);
    afterThirdTestKiloByte = rus.ru_maxrss;
    printf("Third Test should be grater than 0 : %ld\n", (afterThirdTestKiloByte - afterAddKiloByte));
    CU_ASSERT_TRUE( (afterThirdTestKiloByte - afterAddKiloByte) > 0);

    // now free the memmory and get back to the initial value
    for(i=0; i<loops; ++i){
        free(holder[i]);
    }  
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &rus);
    afterForuthTestKiloByte = rus.ru_maxrss;
    printf("Forth Test should be reset to 0 : %ld\n", (afterForuthTestKiloByte - afterAddKiloByte));
    CU_ASSERT_TRUE( (afterThirdTestKiloByte - afterAddKiloByte) == 0);

    puts("- ----------------------- -");
}
```

My output is:

```
- test Memory Free Check  -
- ----------------------- -
- This test takes a while -

Initial KB Used: 458752
After a char add KB Used: 458752
[...]
First Test should be 0 : 0
Second Test should be 0 (4096 is ok for some reasons): 4096
Third Test should be grater than 0 : 1601536
Forth Test should be reset to 0 : 1601536
- ----------------------- -
```

I have two questions that i can't explain myself by now:

1. why is the second Test 4096 and not 0?
2. Why is the Forth test no 0?

The fourth test freaks me out. Please take a look and maybe you can explin how to test a free memory call. I assume that the memory manager do not kill the bytes, but reuse it, so the memory will infect rus.ru_maxrss.
But how can I test the free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory allocated with `malloc` doesn't get returned to the OS, even when `free`'d. Memory is not returned to the OS until program exit.

`getrusage` returns the amount of memory in use by your program as measured by the OS.

Combine the above information and you have your answer to both questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot nightcracker, taht makes sense. but do you know a trick how to tset if a function free'd all allocated space? I have some trouble in a function of a project that i have to write a test for to get it clear and proved.

Comment: @PeterShaw: If my answer solved your problem consider marking it as the accepted answer by ticking the checkbox to the left of my answer.

Comment: @PeterShaw: generally you use a tool like `valgrind` for tests like this. But if you really want to return the memory to the OS you will have to use the API of your OS to allocate/free memory. AFAIK there is no way to make the C runtime do this for you.

Comment: It's a answer to all my both questions, but do you know how i test my function that eats more and more ram? I have to be sure taht i fixed it. TIA.